# Unique element ID

Tags: jquery, unique-key

I am having an issue with unique element id's?

What am I doing wrong here?

http://jsfiddle.net/KRRES/

HTML:

```
<div id='gmapItemHolder'></div>

<button id='btnCreateMarker'>Add</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#btnCreateMarker").click(function () {
    i = 1;
    var gmapItemsHolder = "gmapItems" + i++;

    $('<ul>' + '</ul>')
        .attr({id: gmapItemsHolder, class: 'gmapUlHolder row-fluid'}).prependTo('#gmapItemHolder')
});
```

**UPDATE:**

What happening is that all the newly created ul's get the ID 1

Answer (score 2):

The scope of `i` is local so it does not retain state between clicks.  Increase the scope of `i` so that it is retained between events.

```
  var i = 1;
  $("#btnCreateMarker").click(function () {

      var gmapItemsHolder = "gmapItems" + i++;

      $('<ul>'
         + '</ul>'
         ).attr({id: gmapItemsHolder, class: 'gmapUlHolder row-fluid'}).prependTo('#gmapItemHolder')
  });
```

Comment: *"Make `i` a global variable"* ***Very*** bad idea. Instead, define it in a scoping function around the quoted code. Not a global, but shared by all calls to the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin said, the issue is that `i` is used and thrown away each time.

But **don't** create a global variable as he suggests. Instead, wrap the code in a scoping function and define it there:

```
(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#btnCreateMarker").click(function () {

      var gmapItemsHolder = "gmapItems" + i++;

      $('<ul>'
         + '</ul>'
         ).attr({id: gmapItemsHolder, class: 'gmapUlHolder row-fluid'}).prependTo('#gmapItemHolder')
  }); 
})();
```

That way, `i` is shared by all calls to the `click` event handler, but it is *not* a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var i =jQuery("#gmapItemHolder").children().length + 1;
var gmapItemsHolder = "gmapItems" + i;
```

Instead Of:

```
i = 1;
var gmapItemsHolder = "gmapItems" + i++;
```